# Can't build library which uses Qt5Widgets

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, qt5

I use Ubuntu 18. I try to build assimp library which uses `Qt5Widgets`, CMakeLists.txt contains the following line:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets QUIET)
```

I haven't found "`FindQt5Widgets.cmake`" or "`FindQt5.cmake`" in the system, but the location where Qt5 is installed contains the following directory:

```
/home/user/Qt5/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets
```

which contains the following files:

```
Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake  
Qt5WidgetsConfigExtras.cmake  
Qt5WidgetsConfigVersion.cmake  
Qt5WidgetsMacros.cmake
```

I have tried to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/Qt5/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets
```

or

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/Qt5/5.11.1/gcc_64
```

but it doesn't help.

How to fix that ?

**Edit1**

Warning message:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:439 (MESSAGE):
Build of assimp_qt_viewer is disabled.  Unsatisfied dendencies: Qt5 DevIL
```

Part of the CMakeLists.txt, which causes this warning:

```
 FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets QUIET)
 FIND_PACKAGE(DevIL QUIET)
 FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL QUIET)
 IF ( Qt5Widgets_FOUND AND IL_FOUND AND OPENGL_FOUND)
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( tools/assimp_qt_viewer/ )
 ELSE()
    SET ( ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES "")
    IF (NOT Qt5_FOUND)
       SET ( ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES "${ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES} Qt5")
    ENDIF (NOT Qt5_FOUND)

    IF (NOT IL_FOUND)
       SET ( ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES "${ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES} DevIL")
    ENDIF (NOT IL_FOUND)

    IF (NOT OPENGL_FOUND)
       SET ( ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES "${ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES} OpengGL")
    ENDIF (NOT OPENGL_FOUND)

    MESSAGE (WARNING "Build of assimp_qt_viewer is disabled. Unsatisfied dendencies: ${ASSIMP_QT_VIEWER_DEPENDENCIES}") # Line 439
 ENDIF ( Qt5Widgets_FOUND AND IL_FOUND AND OPENGL_FOUND)
```

I interpret the error message, as `Qt5_FOUND` and `IL_FOUND` variables are false, which means that calls to `FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets QUIET)` and `FIND_PACKAGE(DevIL QUIET)` have been failed. Searching for `DevIL` is *out of scope* of given question.

**Edit2**
Modified FIND_PACKAGE:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
```

**cmake ..** output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:420 (FIND_PACKAGE):
By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
any of the following names:

Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
qt5widgets-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

For all other ways mentioned in the comments (setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or Qt5Widgets_DIR) there is no error message but I still get the following warning:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:439 (MESSAGE):
Build of assimp_qt_viewer is disabled.  Unsatisfied dendencies: Qt5 DevIL
```

Comment: Please, show the error message. It is probably the "standard" one, but nevertheless. And show the rest of the output, especially before the error message.

Comment: Please see Edit, there is also missing DevIL lib but that's a seperate topic.

Comment: Em? How `Qt5Widgets` is related with this error message? In other words, why do you *think* that searching for `Qt5Widgets` is failed?

Comment: FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets QUIET)

Comment: I saw that you show that line in the code, no needs to repeat it. I ask you "why do you think that `Qt5Widgets` isn't found?" The error message you show tells about unrelated thing.

Comment: Please see Edit, I don't know how it works, there is also using a variable Qt5_FOUND which seems to part of the Qt5Config.cmake. I have also tried add to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/user/Qt5/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5 but it doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, now I see that relation. It was actually contained in the error message "Unsatisfied dendencies: **Qt5** DevIL", but I previously treated Qt5 and DevIL as a single thing. That is why my previous clarification request, sorry for that. Unfortunately, given error message has no info about "**Why** CMake treats Qt5 to be not found". This is because *QUIET* option in `FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets QUIET)` line suppresses messages during Qt search. Please, remove this option, and rerun `cmake`. You may also replace the option with *REQUIRED*, so CMake will immediately stop after failing to find QT.

Comment: From my understanding, follow ways should work. 1. `-DQt5Widgets_DIR:PATH=/home/user/Qt5/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets`. 2. `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/home/user/Qt5/5.11.1/gcc_64` (yes, this is what you have already tried). 3. Setting *environment* variable before calling `cmake`: `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/Qt5/5.11.1/gcc_64`. Whether these ways changes a description of why Qt5 isn't found?

Comment: I have added some description to your question post for make a relation between the error message and your problem statement to be clear. This is just what you have written in the comments. Feel free to reword this description if you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please see Edit2.

Comment: Weird, setting `Qt5Widgets_DIR` variable should always help CMake to find `Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake` file. (The other ways normally work, but may fail under certain conditions.) I have no idea why it is not working.